# I cannot update my chart ( in react-chartjs-2 )

Tags: chart.js

I want to update my chart every seconds

Here is my code :

```
class Chart extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            chartData: {
                // my charData
            }
        }

        setInterval(function(){
           this.props.changeHandler();
        }, 500); 
    }


    changeHandler() {
        this.state.update();
    } 

    // my render
}
```

But I have this error : *this.props is undefined* (On the setInterval)

Anyone can help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

function has its own this context so you either have to store the this context in a local variable before the setInterval or use an arrow function instead of function

```
setInterval(() => {
       this.props.changeHandler();
    }, 500);
```

Comment: Thanks ! I will correct it tomorrow...

but this will correct my problem too ?

Comment: I am pretty sure it will

Comment: Okay, and I don't arrive to update my chart with the code I did. There's not an update function with chart-js ?

I tried, on the setInterval to write something like this :
this.props.chartData.datasets.data = this.props.donnees

But there's always something undefined...

Comment: You can update your chart by calling .update() on your chart variable. If you use the react wrapper you will need to look how to access the chart variable

Answer (score 0):

First you need to obtain a [reference to the Chart.js instance](https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2#chartjs-instance).

```
constructor() {
  ... 
  this.chartReference = React.createRef(); 
  ...
}

render() {
  return (
    <Doughnut ref={this.chartReference} data={this.state.data} />
  )
}
```

From this reference, you can obtain the chart instance, update its `data` and finally invoke `chart.update()`.

```
setInterval(() => {
  const chart = this.chartReference.current.chartInstance;
  chart.data.datasets[0].data = [<the new data>];
  chart.update();
}, 2000);
```

Please take a look at this [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-chartjs-2-dynamic-update?file=index.js) and see how it works.